External DLLs and other files are in the nupkg and in the global cache, but not installed with the package
I have a .NET 8 library written in C# that uses an external native C DLL, my library is basically a C# wrapper for the C API. I want to make it a NuGet package and use it in my other projects. Here's the relevant part of the csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
        <PackageReadmeFile>docs/README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="LibLouis/**">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <Visible>false</Visible>
            <PackagePath>lib/$(TargetFramework)/LibLouis</PackagePath>
        </Content>
        <None Include="../../README.md" Pack="true" Visible="false" PackagePath="/docs" />
        <None Include="../../CHANGELOG.md" Pack="true" Visible="false" PackagePath="/docs" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And then I do dotnet pack (I prefer to use Dotnet CLI).
Everything works great, the nupkg gets created, all the files are there in their places (I can clearly see it with 7-zip).
However, if I install the same package either from a local folder or from nuget.org to my other project using dotnet add package, I see only the main DLL (if the package name is foo, it's foo.dll), but no external files mentioned in the <Content> and <None> elements in Csproj. I however do see all the needed files in my %UserProfile%/.nuget/packages folder (global NuGet cache).
I spent several days debugging this, googling, stack-overflowing, microsoft-learning and whatever'ing, but to no avail. I'm desperate.

When you want to bundle native files, there are certain rules to follow because they can be platform dependent. You can find all information how to handle them right there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-files-in-net-packages Hope that helped!
